# Is there a way to take a string check if it is a word then define it?

Tags: iphone, swift, uikit

I have been learning the Swift programming language and have come to a road block. I have figured out how to check if a word is real by using NSString, but I want to know if there is a way to define the word once the word is declared real. Here is the code that declares if it is real.

```
func wordIsReal(word: String) -> Bool {
    let checker = UITextChecker()
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, word.characters.count)
    let misspelledRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWordInString(word, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en")

    return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound
}
```

Comment: Show me your full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Wain you gave me the solution for finding the word.I tried it.

```
let word = "word
if UIReferenceLibraryViewController.dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm(word)
{
    let ref: UIReferenceLibraryViewController = UIReferenceLibraryViewController(term: word)
    self.presentViewController(ref, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Another way Using TextChecker

```
func wordIsReal(word: String) -> Bool 
{
   let checker = UITextChecker()
   let range = NSMakeRange(0, word.characters.count)
   let misspelledRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWordInString(word, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en_US")
   NSLog("misspelledRange:\(misspelledRange)")
   NSLog("word:\(word)")
   let arrGuessed:NSArray? = checker.guessesForWordRange(misspelledRange, inString: word, language: "en_US")as NSArray!
   NSLog("arrGuessed:\(arrGuessed)")
   return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound
}
```

Please see the below answers and solutions

[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603825/swift-open-built-in-ios-dictionary-to-find-word-meaning)

[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419940/access-ios-dictionary-programmatically)

[Error Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259540/uireferencelibraryviewcontroller-hasdictionarydefinition-only-works-in-simulator)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` to both check if there is a definition for the word and display that definition.